# How are iPhone emoji apps made?

Tags: iphone

Does anyone know how it is done?

They seem to be enabling japanese language settings.. But how?

It's impossible to search for it, because of all the outrage over Emoji apps in the app store.

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The language settings are stored in `/User/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preferences.plist` which is on the user partition and isn't sandboxed off from third-party applications.  Enabling Emoji everywhere is a simple matter of adding the `KeyboardEmojiEverywhere` key to this file and giving it a value of `true`.

Answer (score 0):

It's more the case users are kind of hacking the phones to enable the Japanese characters, than apps are specifically enabling it.

I forget how but it did involve a few steps.